# In Excel, how to extract and convert unsorted comma-seperated data from one column into multiple columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, extract

In Excel, I have a table where rows correspond to the respondents of a survey and columns correspond to the respondents' answers to some questions.

When asked what the respondents grow on their fields, they could return a number of cultivars, like cereals, oilseeds, corn, etc.

Unfortunately, all answers to this question were entered into the excel sheet within one cell, seperated by a comma, but not ordered in any way. (A cell might also be empty.)

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Respondent 1 | Cereals,Oilseeds |
| Respondent 2 | Oilseeds,Corn,Cereals |
| Respondent 3 | Corn,Oilseeds |

What I need is a unique column for each possible answer (I can do that by hand as the possible answers are not so many), where in each row there is a "1" if this string is contained in the original cell, and a "0" if the string is not contained in the original cell. The result should look like this:

| Column A | Column B | Cereals | Oilseeds | Corn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Respondent 1 | Cereals,Oilseeds | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Respondent 2 | Oilseeds,Corn,Cereals | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Respondent 3 | Corn,Oilseeds | 0 | 1 | 1 |

I could not figure out any way to do this automatically ... Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Use `=IFERROR(N(FIND(<columnName>,<ColumnBValue>)>0),0)` as one possibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a dynamic array solution(alternative approach), it creates the headers dynamically and spills the `1`s and `0`s as well, it also checks ensures that it does not returns any **`FALSE POSITIVES`**:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, DROP(B1:B4,1),
     b, SEQUENCE(,MAX(LEN(a)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(a,",",))+1)),
     c, UNIQUE(TOROW(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(","&a,",",b),","),2),1),
     w, LAMBDA(x,y,N(ISNUMBER(FIND(","&INDEX(c,,y)&",",","&INDEX(a,x)&",")))),
     VSTACK(c,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(a),COLUMNS(c),w)))
```

---

Test Case One:

[image]

---

If you have the headers spitted separately then, try the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(B2:B4),COLUMNS(C1:E1),LAMBDA(x,y,
 N(ISNUMBER(FIND(","&INDEX(C1:E1,y)&",",","&INDEX(B2:B4,x)&",")))))
```

---

Comment: and thank you too, this works even better!

Answer (score 1):

Put this formula in C2 and copy/paste to the three columns

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(C$1,$B2))),1,0)
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot test it on 365, but to get separate column headers a formula something like this will spill `=UNIQUE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,B2:B4),","))` in C1. Maybe have to use the `=TRANSPOSE(the formula)` to spill in the other coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a VBA Sub to automate Text to Column, this one is for comma separated values but you can get true or false for semicolon, space etc as needed

```
Sub Text2Columns()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
Select Case UCase(ws.Name)
    Case "Sheet2", "Sheet3"
        'do nothing
    Case Else
        ws.Columns(1).TextToColumns Destination:=ws.Range("A1"), 
DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
            Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, _
            Comma:=True, _
            Space:=False, _
            Other:=False, OtherChar:="|", _
            FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 
1)), _
            TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Select
Next ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```